# Understanding &* to access a Rust Arc

Tags: rust

Reading about Condvar (condition variable for Rust) at https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html I stumbled upon:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, Condvar};
use std::thread;

let pair = Arc::new((Mutex::new(false), Condvar::new()));
let pair2 = pair.clone();

// Inside of our lock, spawn a new thread, and then wait for it to start.
thread::spawn(move|| {
    let (lock, cvar) = &*pair2;
    let mut started = lock.lock().unwrap();
    *started = true;
    // We notify the condvar that the value has changed.
    cvar.notify_one();
});

// Wait for the thread to start up.
let (lock, cvar) = &*pair;
let mut started = lock.lock().unwrap();
while !*started {
    started = cvar.wait(started).unwrap();
}
```

What is the `&*pair2` thing? I think it has to do with being able to retrieve the pair from inside the `Arc`, but shouldn't it be better to have a simple `method`  that retrives the internal object of the `Arc` as a reference?

Can somebody explain to me exactly what `&*` does?

Answer (score 9):

The `*` operator turns the `Arc<T>` into `T`. The `&` operator borrows that `T` into `&T`.

So when we put them together, `&*pair` borrows the `Arc<T>` into `&T`.

Another way of writing that code would be:

```
let (lock, cvar) = pair2.deref();
```

Indeed, the original `&*pair2` actually means `&*pair2.deref()` – the `*` forces the compiler to insert a `.deref()` call, and it's *that* method which performs the actual conversion.